# How to make an overridden function private in Dart?

Tags: dart, oop, inheritance, overriding

There is a `_` operator which makes a property private.
Eg: `_hidden()`
This hides the property outside of the file.

Now if I have a `Parent` class with `func()` in the file `parent.dart`.
A `Child` class `extends` the `Parent` class, defined in file `child.dart`.

```dart
// parent.dart
class Parent {
  void func() {
    print("parent");
  }
}


// child.dart
class Child extends Parent {
  
  // How to make this private
  @override
  void func(){
    super.func();
    print("child");
  }
}
```

How can we make the overridden `func()` function private in the `Child` class?

Adding `_` in the `func()` function of the `Child` class doesn't work as the function signature is now changed from the `func()` function of the `Parent` class and hence it is not the overridden function anymore, but a new function.

Comment: "doesn't work as the function signature is now changed" you answer it yourself. you got to ask yourself, do you really need inheritance or composition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a subclass of some type, the subclass has to meet the basic requirements of that type. In other words, in your example the `Child` must implement the same properties and methods as the `Parent` class.

---

I've learned this as "is a" relationship.

Say that you have a hierarchy of a `Duck` at the lowest-level with a `swim()` method, which derives from a `Bird` class that has `fly()`, which in turn has a parent `Animal` class with has `walk()`.

Now, if you have a `Duck` object, you know that it can `swim`, but you also know that it can `fly()` (because it **is a** bird) and `walk()` (because it **is a** animal).

---

Making a public method of the parent class private would violate that "is a" rule and would break a lot of code that depends on the parent class. So while it is valid to have a class `Child` that has a private `_hidden()` method, that class can't be derived from `Parent`, as in order for something to be a valid parent, it *must* have a public `hidden()` method.

In the example I gave above, a `Duck` is a `Bird`, and in order to be a `Bird` you must be able to `fly()`. If you want to model another animal that can also swim, say a `Fish`, you'd give that class a `swim()` method, but not derive it from the `Bird` class.

---

As @Qori commented, if you want yourself wanting to implement some methods from a superclass, but not all of them, you'll want to look at polymorphism, composition and [interface definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791286/how-to-define-interfaces-in-dart) in Dart.